# Check for internet connection in Office task pane apps

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-2012, office-app

I have made a task pane office app which involves the usage of internet (of course). For the successful working, I need to check whether the device is connected to the internet otherwise. If not, the app would crash.

I have checked other questions in MSDN but being a novice, can't relate to my situation.

Could you please tell the procedure and code involved behind this process.

So, that the app informs the user that it isn't connected to the internet and hence can't continue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [navigator.onLine property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms534307%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to find out if the user is online and does not choose to work offline.